# set title of a python `bokeh` plot figure from outside of the `figure()` function

Tags: python, bokeh

I ran into a very seemingly simple problem when using the `bokeh` plotting package in python.

I wanted to set the title of a bokeh figure from outside of the usual figure constructor, but I get a strange error.

Here is the code.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
p = figure()
p.title = 'new title'
```

But when I tried this code, I get an error message:

`ValueError: expected an instance of type Title, got new plot of type str`

So it seems like I need to create a `Title` object or something to pass to the figure. However in the bokeh [documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#Title) there is no mention of how to set the title. There is only mention of how to change the title font or the title color, etc.

Does anyone know how to set the title of the plot from outside of the usual `figure(title='new title')`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edit: Note that the solution in this answer will not work in bokeh server due to [a known bug](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/8865). [This answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51311888/4629950) will work and is more pythonic.

---

You have to assign an instance of `Title` to `p.title`. Since, we are able to investigate the types of things in python using the function `type`, it is fairly simple to figure out these sorts of things.

```
> type(p.title) 
bokeh.models.annotations.Title
```

Here's a complete example in a jupyter notebook:

```
from bokeh.models.annotations import Title
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
output_notebook()
x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, np.pi/100)
y = np.sin(x)
p = figure()
p.circle(x, y)
t = Title()
t.text = 'new title'
p.title = t
show(p)
```

outputs the following chart with the title set to `new title`:

[image: example output]

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info. I was looking at the source code to figure it out, but was not clear on how to set it. Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 30):

To simply change the title without constructing a new `Title` object, you can set the figure's `title.text` attribute:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
p = figure()
p.title.text = 'New title'
```

Comment: This works and is the correct way of doing it according to one of the bokeh developers.